# Creating Subtables from Dataframe Based on Column Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe that looks like this (continuing onward):

[image: .csv table of raw data]

I want to create subtables that are of a dynamic length based on the distance between BUY and SELL. After it matches these two data points and creates the table it would move to the next instance of BUY after the SELL.

i.e. if multiple BUY's exist inside the subtable, it would skip over these to find a SELL point.

The goal is for it to look something like this:

[image: subtable1]

[image: subtable2]

[image: subtable3]

Comment: Why does the last group not go from 11-15?

Comment: @ScottBoston That was my bad, I fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Current Time': ['18:08:20']*16,
                   'Price':np.arange(157.01,157.17,.01),
                   'Moving Avg':[np.nan]*3+list(np.arange(157.01,157.13,.01)),
                   'Action':[np.nan]*3+['BUY']*3+['SELL']*3+['BUY']+['SELL']+['BUY']*4+['SELL']})

#built mock dataframe with fake prices and moving aver

df_new = df[df['Action'].notna()]

grp = (df_new['Action'] == 'SELL').cumsum().shift().bfill()

dd = dict(tuple(df_new.groupby(grp)))

list_of_dfs = [g for _, g in dd.items() if len(g) > 1]

list_of_dfs
```

Output:

```
[  Current Time   Price  Moving Avg Action
 3     18:08:20  157.04      157.01    BUY
 4     18:08:20  157.05      157.02    BUY
 5     18:08:20  157.06      157.03    BUY
 6     18:08:20  157.07      157.04   SELL,
    Current Time   Price  Moving Avg Action
 9      18:08:20  157.10      157.07    BUY
 10     18:08:20  157.11      157.08   SELL,
    Current Time   Price  Moving Avg Action
 11     18:08:20  157.12      157.09    BUY
 12     18:08:20  157.13      157.10    BUY
 13     18:08:20  157.14      157.11    BUY
 14     18:08:20  157.15      157.12    BUY
 15     18:08:20  157.16      157.13   SELL]
```